# Adding an SVG Element and also making it responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I was not able to add an SVG wave type picture to my background AND also make it responsive at the same time. I am trying to add the wave to a pre-existing background image of mine to make it look more appealing. While I was successful in adding one, I soon realized that if I zoomed in on the website, my latest addition acts very funky. Could anyone please share some ideas/code to help me out here?

*What I have already tried*

I did do my research before posting this. I checked out previous questions posted on Stackoverflow and tried to replicate the ideas provided but found no success. This is justified in the code I have posted below.

Following is a snippet of my code.

**HTML**

*This is the section of my code that I am trying to play with.*

```
<section class="site-title">
            <div class="site-background">
                <h1>Who Am I?</h1>

                <h2>I am a 
                <span class="txt-type" data-wait = "5000" data-words = '["example", "example"]'></span>
            </h2>

            <div class = "svg">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1420 320" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><path fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L120,240C240,256,480,288,720,266.7C960,245,1200,171,1320,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
            </div>
</section>

        <!-- Site title.-->


        <!-- Blog posts Carousel. -->
        <section class = "space">
            <div class = "empty"></div>
        </section>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Site Title */

main .site-title{
    background: url(../assets/Wallpaper-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 110vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

main .site-title .svg{
    padding-top: 144px;
    width: 100%;

}

main .site-title .site-background{
    padding-top: 10rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 24px;
}

html,body{
    margin: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier if you consider the SVG as background:

```css
.site-title {
  background: 
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1420 320" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><path fill="white"  d="M0,224L120,240C240,256,480,288,720,266.7C960,245,1200,171,1320,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>') bottom/100% auto,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.site-title .site-background {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="site-title">
  <div class="site-background">
    <h1>Who Am I?</h1>

    <h2>I am a
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="5000" data-words='["example", "example"]'></span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can also consider it as `mask` and you will have transparency:

```css
.site-title {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1420 320" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><path fill="white"  d="M0,224L120,240C240,256,480,288,720,266.7C960,245,1200,171,1320,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>') bottom/100% auto no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
          mask:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1420 320" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><path fill="white"  d="M0,224L120,240C240,256,480,288,720,266.7C960,245,1200,171,1320,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>') bottom/100% auto no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
          mask-composite:exclude;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.site-title .site-background {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<section class="site-title">
  <div class="site-background">
    <h1>Who Am I?</h1>

    <h2>I am a
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="5000" data-words='["example", "example"]'></span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If I zoom in or zoom out the webpage, the effect goes as the size of the curve essentially gets altered too. Is there anything we can do to make it always aligned with the background image?

Comment: if you see the edit now, The first picture depicts the image at a zoom of 100 percent (normal) on Firefox.

The second picture is at a Zoom of 120 percent and the SVG is perfectly aligned with the background.

Comment: @Helpthepoor123 did you copy the exact code here? you have the same issue if you run the snippet here?

Comment: Yep I did copy the exact code. I don't seem to face the same issue on your snippet, however, If i try the same thing with your background as well, I get the same issue highlighted. I don't really know why the zooming affects it so bad.

Comment: @Helpthepoor123 if you don't face the issue in the snippet then for sure you have more code involved or you changed something. Can you verify what difference with my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219494/discussion-between-helpthepoor123-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @Helpthepoor123 did you fix your issue?

Comment: Yep I did thankyou so much @Temani Afif. Was able to use your idea and make some tweaks itself.

The major change I implemented was to set the display of the svg to none. Somehow it was appearing twice and doing this helped me get the output I desired :)